# How to catch and raise tfrecord error in tf.dataset.map in tensorflow < 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Using tfdataset (tensorflow < 2.0) I encounter a rare corrupt file that cannot be cast into the correct dimensions. Each tfrecord line has a filename of an image to be read and the dimensions. I want to catch the error and print this filename so it can be removed.

Where to put the try catch for the parser to raise the filename?

```
def _parse_fn(example):
    # Define features
    features = {
        'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "image/height": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/width": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),

    }

    # Load one example and parse
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, features)

    # Load image from file
    filename = tf.cast(example["image/filename"], tf.string)
    loaded_image = tf.read_file(filename)
    loaded_image = tf.image.decode_image(loaded_image, 3)

    # Reshape to known shape
    image_rows = tf.cast(example['image/height'], tf.int32)
    image_cols = tf.cast(example['image/width'], tf.int32)

    #Wrap in a try catch and report file failure
    try:
        loaded_image = tf.reshape(loaded_image,
                              tf.stack([image_rows, image_cols, 3]),
                              name="cast_loaded_image")
    except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
        print("Image filename: {} yielded {}".format(filename, e))
```

```
    # Maps the parser on every filepath in the array. You can set the number of parallel loaders here. Wrap in a catch loop to report errors
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Error is not caught and filename is not printed

```
File "/apps/tensorflow/1.14.0.cuda10.gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 480000 values, but the requested shape has 259518
     [[{{node cast_loaded_image}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[replica_3/retinanet/bn2c_branch2a/FusedBatchNorm/ReadVariableOp/_987]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 480000 values, but the requested shape has 259518
     [[{{node cast_loaded_image}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
3 derived errors ignored.
```

Answer (score 3):

A colleague suggested this: I will accept if there are no other answers, I think this has some value.

One strategy is to use

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
```

and apply a parsing that returns the filename of each tfrecord. After running this and comparing it to length of the original records, you can find which images was corrupted. I think there must be other solutions, but if you have access to the original set of images that were wrapped into tfrecords, you can diff the lists and get the missing filenames.